# How do I properly setup PHP in my Linux Fedora 19 server?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, fedora

**The Problem:**

This has been going on for quite some time. I only got the installation right once, and after that, it either:

- PHP pages show the PHP codes (not the current error, but I've experienced this)
- PHP pages return "Internal Error in Server"

All I really want is to get PHP to connect to Oracle 11g XE via oci8. I had no idea it would be this difficult.

Additionally, looking into the error logs (I'm assuming this is PHP's error logs) located in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`, reveals the following error:

> PHP Fatal Error: Unknown: Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/html/info.php' (include path =
>   '.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php').

I've never encountered this before.

**The System:**

- Fedora 19 x86_64
- Oracle 11g XE
- Apache 2.4.6
- PHP 5.5.4

**Additional Info:**

info.php contains merely the following:

```
<?php 
phpinfo();
?>
```

`php -i` works, although I'm not sure what to look for there.

**What I tried:**

Plenty. But since I've reformatted the PC, and started over, so here's a break down of what I did:

- Installed Oracle 11g XE
- Properly backed up my database into said Oracle
- Modify .bashrc by adding the following

> TMP=/tmp; export TMP
>       TMPDIR=$TMP; export TMPDIR
>
> ```
> ORACLE_HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain; export ORACLE_HOSTNAME  
> ORACLE_UNQNAME=DB11G; export ORACLE_UNQNAME  
> ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle; export ORACLE_BASE  
> ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.2.0/xe; export ORACLE_HOME  
> ORACLE_SID=XE; export ORACLE_SID  
> NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`; export NLS_LANG  
> ORACLE_TERM=xterm; export ORACLE_TERM  
> PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH; export PATH  
> PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH; export PATH  
>
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH  
> CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/JRE:$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib;
> ```
>
> export CLASSPATH
>
> ```
> if [ $USER = "oracle" ]; then  
>   if [ $SHELL = "/bin/ksh" ]; then  
>     ulimit -p 16384  
>     ulimit -n 65536  
>   else  
>     ulimit -u 16384 -n 65536  
>   fi  
> fi
> ```

- yum groupinstall "Development Libraries"
- yum install httpd
- yum install php

I started apache, configured it to start at boot, was able to get to the Fedora test page, and put a test PHP page in `/var/www/html/` directory.

localhost works fine.

localhost/info.php returns "Internal Error in Server".

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I haven't even gotten PHP up and running yet, so I'm pretty worried about my ability to get it to connect to Oracle. Any ideas / suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Check `/var/error/httpd/*` for a cause to the Internal Error

Comment: I didn't find any directory under `var` named `error`. `empty` is the closest. If you perhaps meant `/var/log/httpd/error_log`, the file says: `PHP Fatal Error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/info.php' (include path = '.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')`. This did not happen before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check permissions on:

```
/var/www/html/info.php
```

I recall having a similar error when the user that was running the apache process didn't have the right permissions for this file.

It's not a good thing to to but you could note down the current permissions of info.php, chmod 777 /var/www/html/info.php and see if it works. If so then that's the problem and try and sort out the issue.

Also check as per @GeoSword instructions of you are getting the php code displayed instead of html as this means that the php configuration in apache is not correct.

Comment: This did the trick, though for some reason after doing `chmod 777 info.php`, said file won't turn up anymore in `ls -l`. The properties are there, but the filename isn't. It is visible in Dolphin, however. It's listed as `-rwxrwxrwx- 1 root root <date> <nothing>`.

Comment: This is another issue. In any case remember that `chmod 777 info.php` is not a good thing! This was just to test and assess that permissions on the file were wrong. What you have to do now is check under what user and group the webserver is running and make info.php rwx for that user/group.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like there's a number of things going on here.

The pages that showed the php code instead of the result of it is probably because the php handler wasn't properly defined in the apache configuration. Redhat installs usually take care of this sort of thing. However something like this is needed somehwhere in your apache configuration to process php files

```
LoadModule php5_module    modules/libphp5.so
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .php5 .phtml
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

The fatal error you're getting is probably down to the error you are seeing in /var/log/httpd/error_log.

It looks like /var/www/html/info.php doesn't exist and your php program really wants it. Im sure I dont need to tell you what to do with that! :)

Comment: The pages that show up as PHP code only happened during my last two attempts to get this working - when I tried to compile PHP as a script (to try and get OCI8 working). Downloading apache and PHP / PHP-devel seems to do the trick, but leaves me lost on how to implement OCI8.